# Avoid Hidden Characters in Config Files

Tags: vb.net, file, config

I have a project which has build up with VB.NET. During the file transfer to server my .config file is changed automatically. When I have open it with notepad++, I realized that, there are some line breaks (LF,CR) and also at the end of the file 'SUB' which means 'End of file' (I'm not sure about this, this is what I found about 'SUB' on the internet, please correct if its wrong).

Is there any special way to avoid hidden characters in config files? or lock the file to keep it original?

Answer (score 1):

The changes are just to do with different encoding on different machines.

The [SUB character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) is an end of file char as you correctly mentioned

You could try setting the file as read-only before transfer to the server. If this is not causing any problem though I would leave it as it is.